# Printing multiple values from mysql database in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to select comments (body, name and timestamp) from a database and then print it on screen. My code so far:

```
$mycomment = db_query('SELECT comment,name,timestamp FROM comments WHERE nid = 246');

while($allcomments = db_result($mycomment)){

print($allcomments);
}
```

My code only prints comment (one value) and I would like to print somethign like "COMMENT posted by NAME on TIMESTAMP". Can anyone help me with the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Drupal [documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database.mysql.inc/function/db_result/5), you should be using either db_fetch_array() or db_fetch_object() instead of db_result().

```
$mycomment = db_query('SELECT comment,name,timestamp FROM comments WHERE nid = 246');

while($allcomments = db_fetch_array($mycomment)){
    print($allcomments['comment'] . ' posted by ' . $allcomments['name'] . ' on ' . $allcomments['timestamp']);
}
```

Comment: and pls answer what is difference between mine and your codes ?

Comment: @DaHaKa This code works in Drupal, you provided more genral one, thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

Start by using `vardump($allcomments)` instead of `print()`

That will at least show you contents of the array, object or whatever is being returned by `db_result`

Than you just need to access that variable appropriately to print out what you want.

Answer (score 0):

$mycomment = mysql_query('SELECT comment,name,timestamp FROM comments WHERE nid = 246');

while($allcomments = mysql_fetch_array($mycomment, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

echo $allcomments['comment'].' posted by '. $allcomments['name']. ' on '. date("g:i a F j, Y ", strtotime($allcomments[ 'timestamp' ]))  ;

}

try this... should work

Comment: Good answer that will work. I especially like how you provided an example to reformat the timestamp if he wants. Being he is working with a Drupal site (which wasn't disclosed in the original question), the only change I would suggest is to use the `db_query()` and `db_fetch_array()` wrapper functions, which will be compatible if the code is distributed or if he ever decides to choose a different database system.